# Mesclar projeto quando usar o comando "composer create-project"

Tags: composer, packagist

Tenho um projeto (um blog) baseado em [laravel/laravel](https://github.com/laravel/laravel) (note que este é a aplicação e não o framework apenas), mas eu desejo enviar pro meu repositório apenas o conteúdo das pastas `app/` e `resources/` (pasta nativas do Laravel), isto eu consegui, o meu problema é no momento de instalar o laravel junto ao meu projeto, ficando apenas isto no meu repositório:

```
.
├── composer.json
├── app
|   ├── BlogHome.php
|   └── Controller.php
└── resources
    └── views
        └── bloghome.blade.php
```

Por exemplo quando rodo o comando:

```
composer create-project [meu vendor]/blog
```

Eu quero que instale junto o [laravel/laravel](https://github.com/laravel/laravel) (a web aplicação Laravel que citei anteriormente) e depois a pasta `app/` e `resources/` do Laravel recebam o conteúdo das pastas que estão no meu repositório.

Desejo fazer desta maneira para que se acaso o [laravel/laravel](https://github.com/laravel/laravel) receba algum update no momento que instalar rodar o comando `composer create-project` já irá instalar da fonte do laravel mesmo, caso contrário eu teria que fazer uma cópia do conteúdo do [laravel/laravel](https://github.com/laravel/laravel) no meu repositório, então qualquer atualização no [laravel/laravel](https://github.com/laravel/laravel) eu teria que fazer manualmente, o que me parece inviável.

Existe alguma maneira de mesclar o meu repositório com o repositório do [laravel/laravel](https://github.com/laravel/laravel) no momento que executar o comando `composer create-project [meu vendor]/blog`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer um script para tal, um .sh que roda o composer create-project, baixa seu repositório e deixa pra você resolver os conflitos do código, ou então comparar com repositório base com o git e aplicar os deltas dos arquivos no seu projeto, mas não vejo qual a razão para se fazer isso.

Somente o código que existe dentro do app é suficiente para a aplicação funcionar? A resposta é não. Ele precisa do código da aplicação base para funcionar e não é garantido que as mudanças nessa aplicação base serão compatíveis com seu código.

O código da aplicação é somente um esqueleto para você começar seu projeto. O que conta mesmo são os componentes do framework (laravel/framework), esses sim precisam ser atualizados e estar funcionando. Você pode até mesmo criar a sua base do zero ou usar outra abordagem, como é o caso do [codecasts/laravel](https://github.com/codecasts/laravel).

Tendo isso claro, que aquele código é só um modelo fica mais fácil de perceber que aquele código não pertence mais ao framework, mas sim ao seu projeto. Nos casos que acontecer algo que te force atualizar as classes base, esse processo estará descrito no [upgrade guide](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade).

Comment: Realmente tem toda razão, o trabalho todo que será feito seria melhor fazer uma copia manualmente do "esqueleto", assim também evitaria problemas acaso o esqueleto mude de formato (igual ocorreu do laravel 5.2 para o 5.3).

Answer (score 0):

Fala Guilherme blzs? O que você ta querendo fazer não seria uma aplicação modular?
Exemplo: Fazer dentro do framework Laravel uma estrutura de pasta para admi e uma outra estrutura de pasta para blog de um empresa.
Se essa e questão existe um jeito de fazer isso no laravel.
Link de um tutorial básico sobre como fazer isso [Módulos Laravel](http://www.laravel.com.br/trabalhando-com-modulos-criando-as-camadas-admin-e-cms/)

Link de um Screencast de como usar. [Aplicações modulares com Laravel 5](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1pIWekdlq10)

Pelo que eu percebi você está faz está fazendo sua aplicação do jeito invertido, já que primeiro você tem que criar a uma aplicação laravel e depois fazer o "modulação" de seus aplicação dentro do framework.

Espero que esse link posso te ajudar! Qualquer coisa é só pergunta. =)

Link de um post em inglês muito bom [Blog Post](http://kamranahmed.info/blog/2015/12/03/creating-a-modular-application-in-laravel/)

Comment: Adriano sei que você já entende um pouco o site, mas gostaria de reforçar, somos um Q&A e não um fórum, aqui as respostas devem ser objetivas, recomendo que formule um exemplo e traga o conteudo dos links para cá editando a sua resposta, assim tornando ela mais relevante. Não somos um fórum nem mesmo de longe, então por favor faça o tour para entender http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour e depois leia o Help http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/answering, entenda como um critica construtiva. Obrigado por compreender.